# Convert Access 2010 accdb to 2007 accdb

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

I'm trying to convert an accdb file from use in Access 2010 to Access 2007. I first tried opening the file with Access 2007 and I get the error `Unrecognized database format`. I was able to get my backend to open in 2007 by removing the `MSysResources` table (which uses the new attachment datatype) but the same technique has not worked with my front end.

My front end does use a webbrowser control (which Microsoft claims won't work but also won't stop the file form being opened). I thought I'd better import one form at a time to see where the error is. While in a new, blank 2007 file I tried to use `External Data`>`Access` to import one form (a very simple form, a button, two text boxes). Same error as opening the whole file. I tried having 2010 open at the same time as 2007 and copy/pasting the form over. Same error. `Unrecognized database format`.

I then try to export the form using `Application.SaveAsText` in 2010 and import using `Application.LoadFromText` in 2007. There were errors importing but at least this method generates an error log. The `error.txt` file has issue with the header line `PublishOption =1`. After I remove that I continually get errors regarding theme settings. I remove every line it has a problem with which are from there on all theme related (`HoverForeThemeColorIndex`, `AlternateBackThemeColorIndex`...). I never did get rid of enough of these to successfully import the form though.

Where am I going wrong? If, like I suspect, I cannot use a theme generated in 2010 in 2007, how can I remove all these references from all my forms? Is this actually the problem? How can I more smoothly move back to a 2007 file?

**Edit:** It turns out the client is on Office 2007 SP2. I'm going to update my development machine and try all this again. I was not using nay service packs originally.

Comment: Does Access 2010 have an option to save the db as 2007 ACCDB format?  Office Button -> Save As ...

Comment: @HansUp It does not have an option to save explicitly as 2007 Accdb as far as I am aware. I can try to save as MDB but I get the same ambiguous error message.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I'll be very interested in hearing how it turns out.

Comment: @GordThompson As far as I can tell this is not possible. The formats are so wildly different that any attempt to merge them fails. I am in the process of making all my forms over again. The tables and code are at least transferable.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Sorry to hear of your misfortune. IMO, the only thing worse than having to fiddle with forms and reports is having to fiddle with forms and reports *again*. :(

Answer (score 3):

According to the Microsoft support article

[Backward compatibility between Access 2010 and Access 2007](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/office/dn602608%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

an Access 2010 database can be reverted back to "Access 2007 format" by

1. removing all Access_2010-specific features from the database (details in the article),
2. creating a new "Blank Database" (not "Blank Web Database"), and
3. using `External Data > Import` in Access 2010 to import all objects (tables, forms, etc.) from the previous database into the new (empty) one.

The list of features that must be removed include a couple that may not be immediately obvious to a casual inspection of the original Access 2010 database, such as

- using a new or updated database sort order, and
- using "Access 2010 encryption compliance".

Comment: (many months later I figured out some more of this puzzle for another project) The one that was particularly not obvious for me at the time was finding all the `Empty Cell Control`s.