# Microsoft Access 2007 - 2010 database compatibility?

Tags: ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

I have a 2007 database that was opened by someone running Access 2010.

They deleted some tables and saved the database but now the database doesn't open on any pc running Access 2007.

I believed that there was compatibility between 2007 and 2010 - I assume I'm wrong?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Another user recently encountered the same problem and posted their question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15822201/convert-access-2010-accdb-to-2007-accdb). Perhaps you could post a comment to that person's question to see if they've made any progress.

Comment: Seeing as this question is a duplicate, you might consider deleting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that even when saving the file in Access 2007 format it does not actually save it with only 2007 compatible syntax. The idiots at Microsoft chose to break backwards compatibility in their rush to release on schedule. Other than recreating your forms and reports you are out of luck.... Hope you kept a copy of your original code.